# Append to the end of a file in C

Tags: c, file, append, fseek

I'm trying to append the contents of a file myfile.txt to the end of a second file myfile2.txt in c. I can copy the contents, but I can't find a way to append. Here's my code:

```
FILE *pFile;
FILE *pFile2;
char buffer[256];

pFile=fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
pFile2=fopen("myfile2.txt", r+);
if(pFile==NULL) {
    perror("Error opening file.");
}
else {
    while(!feof(pFile)) {
        if(fgets(buffer, 100, pFile) != NULL) {
        fseek(pFile2, -100, SEEK_END);
        fprintf(pFile2, buffer);
    }
}
fclose(pFile);
fclose(pFile2);
```

I don't think I'm using fseek correctly, but what I'm trying to do is call fseek to put the pointer at the end of the file, then write at the location of that pointer, instead of at the beginning of the file. Is this the right approach?

Comment: (In addition to the answers below) Your `fseek` idea ought to work, but since you use `SEEK_END` the 'pointer' is already at the very end-- and *then* you go "back" 100 characters. Use `0` for the offset and it ought to work. (Minor: you check if your reading file can open, but not your writing file. Check both.)

Comment: [why while( !feof( file ) ) is never correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Comment: A typo in line 12, The curly brace is'nt closed

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Open with append:

```
pFile2 = fopen("myfile2.txt", "a");
```

then just write to `pFile2`, no need to `fseek()`.

Comment: You should note however that ANSI C does require fseek() or another positioning function.

Comment: @Wyatt8740: where?  My standard says:  "*Opening a file with append mode (a as the first character in the mode argument) shall cause all subsequent writes to the file to be forced to the then current end-of-file, regardless of intervening calls to fseek().*  Granted that is not ANSI C, it is ISO C.

Comment: from GNU's `man fopen`: "Note that ANSI C requires that a file  positioning function intervene between output and input, unless an input operation encounters end-of-file. " Looks like I read it wrong though, it's only when alternating between input and output.

Comment: @Wyatt8740: that's fair enough, and that's my experience as well.  Although I think if I was reading and writing at the same time I would probably use lower-level interfaces than stdio.

Comment: Will using  "a" append from a new line or inline?

Comment: It starts inline(from the same line), obviously unless the last printed character is '\n'

Comment: Line endings are not determined by the open mode (`a`) but by the way you write the characters (note that some implementations have an optional `t` for text or translate which could affect this).  Most interfaces do not add line ending character/s, you have to add them yourself to the stream of bytes being written, but there are a few exceptions, like `puts` for example.  You should read the doc for the writing method in use.

Answer (score 22):

Following the documentation of `fopen`:

> ``a''   Open for writing.  The file is created if it does not exist.  The stream is positioned at
>                the end of the file.  Subsequent writes to the file will always end up at the then cur-
>                rent end of file, irrespective of any intervening fseek(3) or similar.

So if you `pFile2=fopen("myfile2.txt", "a");` the stream is positioned at the end to append automatically. just do:

```
FILE *pFile;
FILE *pFile2;
char buffer[256];

pFile=fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
pFile2=fopen("myfile2.txt", "a");
if(pFile==NULL) {
    perror("Error opening file.");
}
else {
    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), pFile)) {
        fprintf(pFile2, "%s", buffer);
    }
}
fclose(pFile);
fclose(pFile2);
```