# I try to edit .dat file but it does not work

Tags: c, file

I try to edit a file in C but it does not work. The code creates the file if it does not exist but it can not edit it. I tried to change the file opening status but nothing. This is the code :

```
typedef struct{
    char name[MAXSTRING];
    int id;
  }student;


int main(int argc, const char **argv){

        i = 0;
        FILE *fp;
        if ( (fp=fopen("StudentsFile.dat", "w") ) == NULL ){
            printf("FILE CAN NOT OPEN");
        }else{
             printf("INSERT NAME AND ID OF THE STUDENT\n");
            student *stArray = (student *) malloc(sizeof(student));
            scanf("%s" "%d", &stArray->name, &stArray->id);
            while (!feof(stdin))
            {

                fprintf( fp ,"%s", stArray->name );
                scanf("%s" "%d", &stArray->name, &stArray->id);
                printf("%s ", &stArray->name);

            }
            fclose (fp);
         }
             return 0;

     }
```

Comment: How do you know it can't edit it?

Comment: Note `"%s" "%d"` will be merged into `"%s%d"', so the string argument will consume the integer argument. You want it to be `"%s %d"`. EDIT: no, the space in the input should fix that.

Comment: Also, how are you calling the program? If you run it interactively you have to end it with `Ctrl+d` to close `stdin` and let it go out of the loop. If you run interactively and finish with `Ctrl+c` it will quit without calling `fclose`, so it won't flush the buffer and you will not see the writes.

Comment: I copied the code from the university's book and the fclose is out of the loop. That's why I didn't put it in. I followed your instructions and it works. Thank you!!!

Comment: It's correct for it to be out of the loop, but you need to make sure the code after the loop runs, i.e., not quitting abruptly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement seems to be suspected:

```
scanf("%s" "%d", &stArray->name, &stArray->id);
```

It should be:

```
scanf("%s %d", &stArray->name, &stArray->id);
```

Anyway, it seems like you're trying to **append** data into `StudentsFile.dat`. If you use the `w` mode, it'll just write but won't append. You need to use `"a"` mode in this situation.

Therefore, you should create another file pointer as shown:

```
FILE *fp2 = fopen("StudentsFile.dat", "a")
```

Use `fprintf()` for `fp2` rather than `fp1` in this case.

In the while loop, you don't need any `scanf()` because you're trying to append the data into the file.

**Note:** You're missing `%d` for `stArray->id` in `fprintf()` statement and don't forget to close `fp2` after `fp`.

**Here's the clear method to [append text into a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429138/append-to-the-end-of-a-file-in-c)**.