# Unable to append to file in C

Tags: c, file

I am currently writing a program which adds to a list of usernames and also creates a separate user file for a user, yet for some reason my program is acting faulty. My code is:

```
FILE *pF = fopen("usernames.txt", "a+");
fprintf(pF, "\n%s", userName); //adds username to the list of usernames. 
char buf[255]; 
strcpy(buf, userName);
strcat(buf, ".txt"); //creates a variable which matches the file name
FILE *pUser = fopen(buf, "w"); //opens a file with the username of the individual
fprintf(pUser, "%s\n%s", userName, password); //creates a user file
printf("\nYour username has succesfully been registered into the system!\n");
fclose(pUser);
fclose(pF);
```

where the `fprintf(pUser, "%s\n%s", userName, password);` works perfectly but the `fprintf(pF, "\n%s", userName);` doesn't work for some reason?

I tried changing the "a+" to "w" but again the usernames.txt file was not changed so I am not sure how to solve this issue as I can not figure out what is causing it.

Comment: You seem to be missing a `fclose(pF);`.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  How is what you see different than what you expect, and how exactly do you determine that?

Comment: Add some error checking to be sure the file pointers are not NULL before using them. You also don't close `pF` in the code shown.

Comment: @Luatic I had a fclose(pF); later in my code I forgot to add it in the code block, but when I moved it closer to the code I still saw no result

Comment: @dbush I said the usernames.txt file was not changed in the post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429138/append-to-the-end-of-a-file-in-c ("seek" the end of file for each entry)

Comment: Are you looking at the file while the program is running? The buffer will be written when you close.

Comment: @Aditya It helps immensely if you turn your problem into a *stand-alone* program reproducing the error. A bit of effort for you, but *immensely* helpful for everyone here. (And quite often you find your error while creating the example.)

Comment: @Aditya please [edit] and show a [mcve]

Comment: @DevSolar thanks for the suggestion, for some reason when I created a stand-alone program it worked and all the usernames which were meant to be entered from my previous program also uploaded themselves into the usernames file, maybe there was a software issue on my laptop which fixed when I shut it down

Comment: If using mode "w" does not change the file "usernames.txt", then perhaps you have a permissions problem.  If "usernames.txt" is empty, this is not indicated, but if "usernames.txt" has data in it and running your program with mode "w" does not truncate the file, then `fopen` is failing.  You aren't checking the value returned from `fopen`.

Answer (score 1):

1. change the order. If you fail to create user file - you should not add record to "usernames.txt".
2. always check return values `(pF == NULL)`.
3. use \n at the end of the file - it is a standard.
4. you are experiencing your trouble because of missing fclose()
5. snprintf looks better :)
6. also don't forget to validate `username` - if it is user input it can contain a path, and your app could overwrite (or create) arbitrary files.

```
    int add_user(char *username, char *password) {
        char buf[255]; 
        snprintf(buf, 255, "%s.txt", username)

        FILE *pUser = fopen(buf, "w"); //opens a file with the username of the individual
        if (pUser == NULL) {
            return 1;
        }
        fprintf(pUser, "%s\n%s", userName, password); //creates a user file
        fclose(pUser);

        FILE *pF = fopen("usernames.txt", "a+");
        if (pF == NULL) {
            return 1;
        }
        fprintf(pF, "%s\n", userName);
        fclose(pF);
        return 0;
    }

<...>

if (add_user("user", "password")) {
    fprintf(stderr, "an error occured");
    exit(1);
}
printf("Your username has succesfully been registered into the system!\n");
```

Comment: Errors belong on stderr.  Always.  `fprintf(stderr, "...");`

Comment: William Pursell, thank you. Fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

If `usernames.txt` is non-empty and running the program with mode `w` does not change the file, then `fopen` is almost certainly failing.  You must check the value returned by `fopen`.

```
const char *path = "usernames.txt";
const char *mode = "a+";
FILE *pF = fopen(path, mode);
if( pf == NULL ){
        perror(path);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Error checking is not optional, even though many examples and tutorials will omit it for the sake of brevity.